# Create an Address class

Tags: python, class

I'm having huge problems understanding classes. I have to create an address class with the instance variables: street, city, state and zipcode and then I have to add a `__str__` method that returns a string printing the instance variables.

sorry! here is the code I have right now
my issue is trying to get the instance variables printed, because right now they are undefined.

```
class Address:

def __init__(self, street, city, state, zipcode):
    self.street = street
    self.city = city
    self.state = state
    self.zipcode = zipcode

def get_street(self, street):
    return self.street

def get_city(self, city):
    return self.city

def get_state(self, state):
    return self.state

def get_zipcode(self, zipcode):
    return self.zipcode

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.street,self.city,self.state,self.zipcode)

street = Address(Grandview)
street.get_street
city = Address(Westland)
city.get_city
state = Address(Michigan)
state.get_state
zipcode = Address(48186)
zipcode.get_zipcode
print(street, city, state, zipcode)
```

Comment: Post your code and describe where you're stuck.

Comment: `class Address()` would be a good start. Can you [edit] your post, please?

Comment: That's a nice story, but what is your question? It sounds to me like you should be [working through a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), because this site is not for tutoring you.

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: Now explain what the specific issue is with that code.

Comment: you have defined class correct but instantiating and calling `__str__ ` method wrong. Use `myAddress = Address("123 Grandview", " Westland" , "Michigan", "48186")` to instantiate and `print myAddress` to print contents using `__str__` method.

Comment: It takes a well of arrogance to vote down a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `class __init__(...)` to **pass 4** `arguments`:

```
def __init__(self, street, city, state, zipcode):
```

But pass only **one** undefined `Grandview`:

```
street = Address(Grandview)
```

You have defined e.g. `get_street(...)` as a function:

```
def get_street(self, street):
return self.street
```

but uses it as a `class attribute`:

```
street.get_street
```

I suggest to read:
[python-websites-tutorials](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-websites-tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

Based on you code, it should be:

```
class Address:

    def __init__(self, street, city, state, zipcode):
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode

    def get_street(self, street):
        return self.street

    def get_city(self, city):
        return self.city

    def get_state(self, state):
        return self.state

    def get_zipcode(self, zipcode):
        return self.zipcode

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.street,self.city,self.state,self.zipcode)

address = Address('Grandview', 'Westland', 'Michigan', 48186)
street = address.get_street()
city = address.get_city()
state = address.get_state()
zipcode = address.get_zipcode()

print "%s, %s, %s, %s" % (street, city, state, zipcode)
```